# nginx forward url without showing end results

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to forward all incoming traffic on my domain (cafe.com) by:

> if ($host = 'coffee.cafe.com' ) {
>                   rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://www.cafe.com/homepage/?path=coffee permanent;
>               }
>
> if ($host = 'tea.cafe.com' ) {
>                   rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://www.cafe.com/homepage/?path=tea permanent;
>               }

While this is working fine, I don't want visitors to see the whole "homepage/?path=coffee" part. Is there a way for me to hide "homepage/?path=coffee" from them in URL? and just show coffee.cafe.com or tea.cafe.com (what they originally typed in URL)

Thanks in advance for all the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you should understand the difference between 'rewrite' and 'redirect', rewrite means modify uri in server side and do not require another request from user, redirect means server side returns a new url and ask client side to start a new request with this new url. The [manual](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) of redirect directive.

Here, you using rewrite directive with 'http://' and 'permanent' modifier. It means 301 redirection, this ask client side to post a new request with the specific url, thus, users will see the new url.

You should change your conf file, to **make sure the virtual host accept all these Hosts**:

```
server {
    listen **;
    server_name .cafe.com;
    .....
}
```

Then, 'tea.cafe.com' or 'coffee.cafe.com' or 'www.cafe.com' just the same for the server. If you want to do some different things for different host, you can just use:

```
if ($host = 'coffee.cafe.com' ) { 
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /homepage?path=coffee break; 
}
if ($host = 'tea.cafe.com' ) { 
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /homepage?path=tea break; 
}
```

Notice that no 'http://' in destination url and 'break' modifier.

Comment: New `server` block is the right way to do this, [`if` is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) . You must use locations and servers instead of `if` if it's possible. `Rewrite` sometimes [also evil]( http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites) , so pleace replace it with `return`.